# Android Studio / Gradle Build questions

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm slowly starting to port my existing apps to Android Studio and Gradle. I have a few questions about it though before I get too far.

Is it possible to build a signed apk outside of Android Studio, from a command line, like you can with ant.

Is it possible to build a signed apk for every variant all in one go, again outside of the UI.

Finally, this is a situation that won't affect many people, but is there a limit on the number of variants you can realistically have. I am probably looking at having between 2000-4000 separate variants. Is this going to be a complete no go?

Comment: yes, yes, 2000-4000 omg! it will be hard to maintain even with gradle ... check gradlew.bat/gradlew in project folder and play with command line args ... still i'm not sure if AndStu is ready for production ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes
2. yes
3. hmm that's quite a lot. I think there are going to be issues. For instance right now Gradle doesn't let us parallelise the compilation of the variants, so it's going to take forever to build. Also, you might run out of RAM when setting up the internal model that represent all the variants and their associated properties and tasks.

I guess you should just try it and see. Using simple groovy code you should be able to dynamically create 2000 flavors in an empty projects and then see if you can compile without problem.